# Preventing multiple borrows in concurrent operations

Tags: concurrency, rust

I'm trying to parallelize an infinite impulse response filter, represented as a cascade of biquads:

[image: An infinite impulse response filter, represented as a cascade of biquads]

The input data is divided into 5 chunks (the columns). The IIR has 3 biquad cascades (the rows). To run a biquad (one of the blocks), both the data to the immediate left and below the block must have been computed. The number in the block represents the earliest ordering of computation possible for that block.

I'm using [`mpsc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/index.html) and [scoped_threadpool](https://crates.io/crates/scoped_threadpool) to try and build an algorithm that can compute as many blocks in parallel as possible.

```
extern crate scoped_threadpool;

use scoped_threadpool::Pool;
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;

fn main() {}

pub struct BiQuad {}

impl BiQuad {
    pub fn new() -> BiQuad {
        BiQuad {}
    }

    #[inline]
    pub fn apply(&mut self, _data: &mut [f64]) {}
}

pub struct Filter {
    biquads: Vec<BiQuad>,
}

impl Filter {
    pub fn new() -> Filter {
        Filter {
            biquads: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn add_biquad(&mut self, biquad: BiQuad) {
        self.biquads.push(biquad);
    }

    pub fn apply_concurrently(&mut self, data: &mut [f64], threads: usize) {
        apply_concurrently_internal(&mut self.biquads, data, threads);
    }
}

fn apply_concurrently_internal(biquads: &mut [BiQuad], data: &mut [f64], threads: usize) {
    if !biquads.is_empty() {
        let mut pool = Pool::new(threads as u32);
        let (tx, rx) = channel();
        let tx2 = tx.clone();
        let chunk_size = data.len() / threads;

        tx.send((0, 0, data.split_at_mut(chunk_size), biquads.split_at_mut(1)));

        pool.scoped(|scope| {
            loop {
                match rx.recv() {
                    Ok((
                        biquad,
                        block,
                        (chunk_data, remaining),
                        (current_biquad, cascading_biquads),
                    )) => {
                        let inner_tx = tx2.clone();

                        println!("got here: {} - {}", biquad, block);

                        scope.execute(move || {
                            current_biquad[0].apply(chunk_data);

                            //Move horizontally (through data)
                            inner_tx.send((
                                biquad,
                                block + 1,
                                remaining.split_at_mut(chunk_size),
                                (current_biquad, cascading_biquads),
                            ));

                            //Move vertically (cascade)
                            inner_tx.send((
                                biquad + 1,
                                block,
                                (chunk_data, &mut []),
                                cascading_biquads.split_at_mut(1),
                            ));
                        });
                    }
                    Err(_) => break,
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

([playground](http://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=087b4bcee4311ff86920c55c72a81c6c&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

After computing the first block, I want to signal that 2 blocks are available (1,0 and 0,1). The slice of biquads cannot be sent to both blocks, that's a borrow violation:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*cascading_biquads` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:77:33
   |
69 |                                 (current_biquad, cascading_biquads),
   |                                                  ----------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
77 |                                 cascading_biquads.split_at_mut(1),
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
78 |                             ));
79 |                         });
   |                         - first borrow ends here
```

Furthermore, as written, there's nothing preventing block 2,2 from being executed 3rd instead of at least 4th.

Is this a problem I can solve elegantly with Rust's (fearless!) concurrency features? Are there any patterns for working around cases where concurrent operations both share data and have dependencies on one another?

Comment: *Don't communicate by sharing memory; share memory by communicating.*

Comment: I think your approach is a bit wrong. You will never need more than three threads, one per row. Each row will process its cells from left to right. Processing a cell will block on its down neighbour being ready (it's left neighbour _must_ be ready)

Comment: @PeterHall, I agree that it is wrong. The problem is the threads need to be diagonal across the grid. If the dependency was simply one way, it would be easy.
Shepmaster, are you saying that the shared memory is the data and biquad and should be fetched upon receiving the message? I tried that, but I run into the same problem once the thread in the pool tries to get shared data, it needs to borrow it from somewhere...

Comment: *once the thread in the pool tries to get shared data, it needs to borrow it from somewhere* — but why share anything at all, especially mutable things? Fan out the work to threads, send it back to one thread to store it somewhere. Otherwise, you are very likely to be strung out to dry by false sharing.

Comment: There's a performance hit if each thread has to work on a copy of the data.

Comment: You cannot make such a statement about this code because you don't have working code to benchmark. Are you already aware of false sharing? Are you preventing it somehow? That's a straightforward case of when sharing makes your code slower. Additionally, there are multiple ways to *transfer* ownership of something instead of *copying* it.

Comment: I said borrow, but you're correct what I really want is ownership transfer (which is what the sample code doing by sending slices and biquads to the receiver, right?) I think the problem is to transfer the ownership of both the biquad and the slice of input data to the thread that is doing the work, but once that thread is done, to transfer the data and biquad to new, but different threads.